# JQGRID: Trigger Reload not working on iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a web page with an iFrame. It loads a web page (same domain) with a jqGrid table. What I'm trying to do now is:

- You press a link called `search` it opens a dialog with a filter form to filter your search.
- When you press `search` button inside the dialog, it changes jqGrid url param and it should `.trigger('reloadGrid')`.

It does all except the `reloadGrid`, I don't know why.

Any suggestion?

Code:

```
// DIALOG-ACTION-SEARCH IS THE BUTTON CLASS
$('#dialog').find('.dialog-action-search').button({icons: {
    primary: 'ui-icon-search'
}, text: true}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content-center').contents().find('#list').setGridParam({
        url: 'filteredsearch.html?option=1'
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    $('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
    $('#dialog').remove();
});
```

Comment: What is your `datatype` set for in the grid's initial setup?

Comment: `json`, the problem is that I don't get any error. It's like never gets reloaded, as if couldn't reload for some reason. It changes the `url`, because I press refresh button at the `navGrid` of my jqGrid and it throws an error because the url does not exist already. Also, tried with an `url` that exists and recieves no data. My jqGrid when press the refresh button gets empty, but stil not trigger `reloadGrid`.

Comment: See my answer.  If that doesn't work, have you fiddled it to see if it ever actually makes the call?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that before calling `trigger('reloadGrid')` with JSON data, you should reset the `datatype` parameter.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
```

In response to your comments, I would split up the chained method calls and then put a breakpoint on `e.preventDefault()` in Chrome debugger so you can assure that everything is actually getting hit.

```
$('#dialog').find('.dialog-action-search').button(
    { 
        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-search' } ,
        text: true
    });
$('#dialog').find('.dialog-action-search').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var grid = $('.content-center').contents().find('#list');
    $(grid).jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: 'filteredsearch.html?option=1' });
    $(grid).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
    $(grid).trigger('reloadGrid');
    $("#dialog").dialog('destroy');
    $("#dialog").remove();
});
```

While I'm a fan of chaining when you can, in this case I don't think you're going to find the root of the issues without doing things a little more explicitly, especially when using `.find`.  How do you know that the `.find` is actually returning the element that you want?

Comment: I tried it, but still not working :S The new url is set, all is set, because I've checked with Chrome when I press refresh button, that it sends a request to the new url to retrieve data.

Comment: So you can actually see it sending the request?  Is there a Javascript error in Chrome debugger?  Better yet, have you used Fiddler to track the request and response?

Comment: It sends the request when I press `refresh` button at `navGrid`. It is not doing it automatically as it should with `.trigger('reloadGrid');`. Then, that method is never executed, I don't know why. It's not giving a Javascript error in Chrome debugger and I did not upload a Fiddle to show an example because I don't know if it will work properly with an iFrame

Comment: I also tried to remove all and only accessing to the list and try to reload it with `$('.content-center').contents().find('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');` and it's not working too.

Comment: Never used it, but I told you that is not working. Chrome does not show any request on `network` tab. Also, when I load the page, the grid is filled up with some data, but when you try to filter it should show empty grid, because I did not implement filters on server side and It does only when I press refresh button of jqGrid `navGrid`, It's never trigering `reloadGrid`.

Comment: Well, that was my fault. Initially, the web page has a left menu. When you click the first option (HTML anchor), it loads the grid into the iframe (changes `src` value of the iframe) and displays (at bottom from first option) a "submenu" (more HTML anchor). There I have the search link, that when I click it, loads a dialog with a form and the button there. When the form is loaded, it should recognize that there is a jqGrid. In fact, I use `console.log(list.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'url'));` and it shows the current url specified on the jqGrid before it changes. Also tried your edit. No result :(

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time, but seems that I will have to add an action button into my `navGrid` that opens that dialog that I've already made. See you and thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

`setGridParam` returns a `jqGrid` object, not a `jQuery` object, so I'm pretty sure you can't chain the `trigger` method. Try this instead:

```
var list = $('.content-center').contents().find('#list')
list.setGridParam({
    url: 'filteredsearch.html?option=1'
})
list.trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried this and it's not working :S

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same problem. I did not have time to investigate why it was happening but found a workaround for it.
In a javascript file that loads inside iframe with your grid I declared

```
window.top.reloadEventList = function () {
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");};
```

Then just call

```
window.top.reloadEventList()
```

instead of

```
list.trigger('reloadGrid')
```